# what is the error in the following lines of c code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *head,*temp;

void insert()
{
   struct node *var;
   head=NULL;
   var=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   printf("enter the data:");
   scanf("%d",var->data);
   temp=head;
   if(head==NULL)
   {
     head=var;
     head->next=NULL;
   }
   else
   {
     while(temp->next!=NULL)
     {
       temp=temp->next;
     }
     if(temp->next==NULL)
     {
       temp->next=var;
       temp=temp->next;
       temp->next=NULL;
     }
   }
 }

 void display()
 {
     temp=head;
     if(temp==NULL)
     {
        printf("empty list");
     }
     while(temp->next!=NULL)
     {
       printf("%d",temp->data);
       temp=temp->next;
     }
 }

 void main()
 {
     int value,choice;
     printf("\nenter choice:");
     scanf("%d",&choice);
     while(choice==1)
     {
        insert();
        display();
        printf("\nenter choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
     }
     getch();
 }
```

i have made a linklist using c above but the code is not displaying the linklist,instead it shows null pointer compilattion as output,how to solve the problem,i'm new to c coding so cant find adequate solution for this ????

Comment: Is SO a debugging service?

Comment: At least fix the indentation first.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Post explicit questions in which it is clearly shown what have you tried, what were the expected outputs and what did you get.

Comment: At least `struct node` shold also be know.

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("%d",var->data); 
//--> scanf("%d",&(var->data));
```

`scanf`'s argument must be pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

With every insert, you reset `head` to `NULL`. So you will always insert new values at the head and any existing values will be just left in memory, leading to a memory leak.

I guess you want to move the line `head=NULL;` to the beginning of the main method.

And fix your `scanf` like keeptalk said.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing to initialise `*var`'s member `next` after having allocated `*var` using `malloc()`.